# Defining a unique pointer in a header file with a custom deleter defined externally

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am converting my code to use unique_ptr instead of just pointers. I am trying to create a unique_ptr to a sqlite3_statement that automatically calls the function  sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt) in its custom deleter. How can I get this to work in my header file? I am completely at loss here, any help is welcome. Thanks.

With a lot of help from igleyy ( his solution gave me memory access errors when the deleter was called for some reason) I came up with this solution that seems to work and looks elegant;

Datasource.h

---

```
#pragma once
#include <sqlite\sqlite3.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Datasource
{

    void statementDeleter(sqlite3_stmt* object);
    std::unique_ptr<sqlite3_stmt, std::function<void(sqlite3_stmt*)>> statement;

    Datasource(Datasource const &);
    Datasource &operator=(Datasource const &);

public:
Datasource(void);
~Datasource(void);
};
```

Datasource.cpp

---

```
#include "Datasource.h"

Datasource::Datasource(void) : 
statement(nullptr,std::bind(&Datasource::statementDeleter,this,std::placeholders::_1))
{
}

void Datasource::statementDeleter(sqlite3_stmt * s)
{
sqlite3_finalize(s);
}

Datasource::~Datasource(void)
{
}
```

Comment: You can't.  The deleter is part of the `unique_ptr`'s *type*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write simple lambda expression like this:

```
auto d = [](sqlite3_stmt* stmt) { sqlite3_finalize(stmt); };
std::unique_ptr<sqlite3_stmt, decltype(d)> statement(new sqlite3_stmt, d);
```

**Explanation**

Custom deleter is created using lambda expression and stored in variable of automatically recognized type. `decltype` is used to obtain type of expression (which in your case you must provide while creating `unique_ptr` to feed it with your custom deleter).

**Edit**

There are two statement variables in your Datasource class code, you need to rename one of them. You cannot initialize `d` and first `statement` variables like this. I think there is no possibility to use auto in such context, but we can use `std::function`. Include  and replace `auto d ...` with `std::function<void(sqlite3_stmt*)> d;`. Initialize `d` in constructor initialization list.
Change `statement` to  `std::unique_ptr<int, decltype(d)> statement;` and also initialize it in constructor initialization list.

```
Datesource::Datasource() : 
  d([](sqlite3_stmt* stmt) { sqlite3_finalize(stmt); }), 
  statement(new sqlite3_stmt) { /* constructor code */ }
```

Comment: Hi entering this in my header file VC2012 gives me the following errors; -Error cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required) on the d and 'Error  a lambda is not allowed in a constant expression' on the []. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show where in your code you pasted `auto d ...` expression?

Comment: Immediately after the class definition in my header file replace the std::unique_ptr in my code above. Besides the class constructor and deconstructed there is nothing else defined.

Comment: See the edited post above second code block, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Aktaeon I updated my answer to explain why it didn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry about that it was commented out before, I am trying bstamour's solution at the same time. Even after deleting the second statement I have the same error :( As mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a custom deleter that frees the statement:

```
struct sqlite_finalizer {
    void operator()(sqlite3_stmt*& s) const {
        sqlite3_finalize(s);
        // ... anything else.
    }
};
```

and then make a custom typedef for it:

```
using sqlite3_handle = std::unique_ptr<sqlite3_stmt, sqlite_finalizer>;
sqlite3_handle handle;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that unique ptr is not the way to go on this one. I say this because the stdlib already has a parallel to this for mutexes called [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard), you can't use `lock_guard` but the idea is the same. Make a class called `sql_stmt_guard` or something. Basically how it would  work is on construction it would do the setup methods on the statement and the destructor would call `sqlite3_finalize`. `lock_guard` (or `unique_lock` when the situation arises) in c++ is considered idiomatic and is very useful because RAII gives you the guarantee that the `unlock` method will run, and for you the guarantee that your `sqlite3_finalize` will get called